# How to do this image border animate on hover? Jquery or CSS? unsure

Tags: jquery, css, hover, border, animated

I found this link on a forum, and like the effect also,

http://livedemo00.template-help.com/osc_35398/

under the new products links, the images when you hover over, have a black border which is animated quickly.

i looked through the css and found several divs, but not sure how it is being done, whether jquery is involved.

any tips would be great.

i just realised its not working on ie 8, but its working on firefox.
http://livedemo00.template-help.com/osc_35398/

Yes i've checked the css and found multiple divs which are using a small png image, and used firebug, but its not giving me anything specific for this effect. it may be jquery, im not sure.

cheers

Comment: Why not look at the source to see how it's done? Also, your link won't load for me.

Comment: plz read this section http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is a fantastic tool that allows you to inspect dom, CSS and HTML.

Is it Java script? 
Turn off Javascript in your browser and see.
Is it CSS ?
Use Firebug and source code inspection in almost any browser.

It def look like Javascript.